# Are animation markers part of the timeline or part of an action?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to use animation markers for events in a game engine. I added several actions to a test file and a few markers.

The markers seem to be the same in all actions, and editing a marker with one action active changes the marker in the other actions.

So the question is, are animation markers stored similar to keyframes inside an action, or are they stored outside the animation? Are they purely meant as an editing tool? Is there a separate mechanism to mark animation events or do I need to script something myself?

Comment: Perhaps you could better define "animation" event. I suspect that you're not being granular enough in your actions. That is, if you're defining multiple "animations" within a single action, then that should probably be further broken up into smaller actions.

Comment: Animation events are used for example to trigger sound effects or particle systems. Or for example to mark the point in an attack animation where damage should be applied. CoDEmanX's answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends, there are **Timeline Markers** and **Pose Markers**.

[Timeline markers](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.timeline_markers) are stored at scene level, whereas [Pose markers](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.types.Action.html#bpy.types.Action.pose_markers) are stored in an action:

```
# Timeline markers of current scene
bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers

# Pose markers for 'CubeAction'
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction'].pose_markers
```

In the *Dope Sheet* editor, switch to *Action Editor*.

Click the menu *Marker > Show Pose Markers* to see pose markers.

With this enabled, creating markers will add pose markers!
(Pose markers show a diamond-shaped icon)

With *Show Pose Markers* disabled, you may select Timeline markers (they show a triangular icon) and click *Marker > Make Markers Local* to convert them to Pose markers. Note that the original Timeline marker will be gone. If you want to keep it, make a duplicate before you convert (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>).