# Has "Show pose markers" option been deleted in blender 4.0?

Tags: animation, actions, marker

I am trying to add Action-specific markers in blender 4.0...
By googling I found this thread
[Are animation markers part of the timeline or part of an action?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/are-animation-markers-part-of-the-timeline-or-part-of-an-action), but couldn't find the option when I tried to check the "show pose markers" checkbox myself.

If it is no longer there, is there any equivalent of pose markers(markers specific to actions)?

[image]

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/animation/markers.html#marker-pose-add) is the Blender 4 manual section on Pose Markers. (I've never had occasion to use them myself.)